# 14.04 trusty randomly freezing

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I recently switched to 14.04, my laptop config are:
4Gb Ram, Intel core i5 proc 2.4 Ghz
I keep Ubuntu updated, but I have a persistent problem of it hanging/freezing randomly.
The system becomes unresponsive with mouse and keyboard shortcuts not working and the screen freezes which forces me to use power button to restart manually.
Although I have noticed one particular thing, Last time when that happened I was watching a video, but the audio kept playing after the freeze, is this possibly a graphics problem? Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes).

but if you repeatedly experiencing this problem [reinstalling Unity](http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/) will Solve your problem.
also give a  Try to boot Ubuntu in Safe mode.for that choose advanced option from Grub Options.